# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-imagebutton

My app is only crashing on certain Android devices, with an inflation error regarding a v7 AppCompatImageButton. Since these buttons work fine on most of the devices that run my app i'm having trouble understanding why they don't inflate properly on others (like the Moto X for example).

I initially thought that the use of `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` instead of an explicit color hex code could be causing the issue, but alas the button still fails to inflate even if I change this attribute to `android:background="#00000000"`.

Can anyone offer insight into whats causing some phones to fail to inflate this xml Button?

Inflating code

```
public class FragmentEasyChordMenu extends Fragment implements EasyChordAdapter.onItemClickListener {
private static ImageButton mBtnAddMarker, mBtnRemoveMarker;

private View mPopupView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_easychord, container, false);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mPopupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.easy_chord_menu, null); //ERROR Here

    ...

}
```

}

```
                    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/removeMarker"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_black_24dp"
                        android:tint="#C4252C"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Full stack trace:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.guitarsimtechnologies.guitarsim, PID: 10146
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.guitarsimtechnologies.guitarsim.FragmentEasyChordMenu.onCreateView(FragmentEasyChordMenu.java:79)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1231)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:
```

Comment: Show your inflating code

Comment: @PhátPhát Added